# Between any two points of a straight line, there always exists an unlimited number of points.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I've come across the following problem while skimming over *Foundations of Geometry* by David Hilbert.

> Between any two points of a straight line, there always exists an unlimited number of points.

First, I was given the following advise:

> Given a line $a$ and a point $P$ not lying on the line, we say that a point $q$ is on the same side of $a$ as $P$ iff there is no point of $a$ in the segment $PQ$ and we say the point $q$ is in the opposite side of $a$ as $P$ in the opposite case.

> Prove that "being on the same side" is an equivalence relation.

Now, say such relation is $\equiv;$ then the difficult part of it is proving the transitivity property, namely, that if $P\equiv Q$ and $Q\equiv R$ then $P\equiv R.$ By Pasch axiom this is trivial if $P,Q$ and $R$ are not collinear, however, if the three are collinear, I have no idea how to prove it...Of course this would lead to the resolution of the main Theorem, but I'm having a lot of difficulties proving that using the Axioms given in Hilbert's book.

Thank you for your help!.

Comment: Of course, the resolution to this will depend on precise statements of the axioms Hilbert uses, and there are a lot of them.  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms) is a convenient list.

Comment: See [this near duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498331/existence-of-a-point-between-two-points-in-hilbert-geometry).

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $P$ and $R$ are distinct points. Then we can find two points $B, C$ between  $P$ and $R$. We can arrange them in order $P, B, C, R$. Then take three points $P=Q, B, C$ - point $B$ lies between $Q$ and $C$. On the other hand, take $B, C, R=Q$ then $C$ lies between $B$ and $Q$. This contradicts the axiom that "Of any three points situated on a straight line, there is always one and only one which lies between the other two."

Comment: How can you produce "two points $B,C$ between $P$ and $R$"?  That would seem to be the point of the exercise, no?

Comment: @lulu: that's one of the axioms of order: If A and C are two points of a straight line, then there exists at least one point B lying between A and C and at least one point D so situated that C lies between A and D.

Comment: This is not one of the axioms as stated on the wikipedia page, perhaps it appears elsewhere?

Comment: I am looking at the book mentioned by the OP

Comment: @lulu: It seems the second axiom of order on wiki page stated differs from what I see in the Hilbert's book. Should probably trust Hilbert :)

Comment: I think the issue may be different.  The duplicate I linked to appears to contain a proof that the other axioms imply the existence of a point between two given points, which (if correct) would make the axiom as stated by Hilbert redundant.  Like the $21^{st}$ axiom which most sources now delete as redundant.  In any case, if you can always find a point between two fixed points then you can just iterate to get "unlimitedly" many.

Comment: It's interesting.  I just checked [Hartshorne](https://download.tuxfamily.org/openmathdep/euclid/Euclid_and_Beyond-Hartshorne.pdf) and, on page $73$ he gives (more or less verbatim) the axiom as presented in Wikipedia (I think they might have copied from this text).  Not sure what the official list is, if there even is one.   (Note:  that Hartshorne's exercise $7.6$ asks the reader to deduce the existence of a point between two specified points from the stated axioms).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $P,Q,R$ are three distinct collinear points and $P \equiv Q$ and $Q \equiv R$, but $P \not \equiv R$. It follows that the segment $\overline{PR}$ intersects the line $a$ at some point $X$. Clearly $X \notin \{P,Q,R\}$. Given the four points $P,Q,R,X$, there is an arrangement of them as $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$ such that $A_2$ is between $A_1$ and $A_3$, while $A_3$ is between $A_2$ and $A_4$ (this is Hilbert's discarded axiom which actually follows from other axioms). Since $Q,X$ are between $P$ and $R$, we have $\{Q,X\}= \{A_2,A_3\}$ and $\{P,R\}=\{A_1,A_4\}$. It follows that either $Q=A_2$ and $X=A_3$ or $Q=A_3$ and $X=A_2$. In either case, either $X$ is between $P$ and $Q$ or between $Q$ and $R$. Since $P \equiv Q$ and $Q \equiv R$, we have reached a contradiction.